# Strange behavior with IE tabs in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, tabs, undefined-behavior

The code below searches through all the open explorer instances looking for "Internet Explorer" and a specific URL.  If the URL is found the function returns the IE instance back to the calling subroutine. Otherwise, if the URL is not found, but IE is already open, then the function opens a new tab with the passed URL (my_url). Or, if IE is not open, the function opens a new instance of IE and navigates to the passed URL.

Everything works as desired except for one line: `IE_sub.navigate my_url, 2048 'new tab`. Here is what happens: when the function is called it correctly identifies an Internet Explorer object and sets IE_sub to that object (if IE is already open). However, when the .navigate call is made with the 2048 option (a new tab), the code opens a new instance of IE that has two tabs: one is the tab it found during the previous loop and the other is the new tab. In other words, a new tab does not open within the existing IE object, rather a whole new IE instance is created. I even tried the code `IE_sub.Parent.navigate my_url, 2048` thinking I could reference the parent of the tab, but the results were the same (i.e. the code worked but still opened a new instance of IE instead of a new tab within the existing IE window)

Here is the applicable code:

```
Function GetIE(my_url As String) As InternetExplorer
    Dim shellWins As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim explorer As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim found As Boolean: found = False
    Dim IE_sub As Object

    Set shellWins = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

    For Each explorer In shellWins
        If explorer.name = "Internet Explorer" Then
            Set IE_sub = explorer
            If explorer.LocationURL = my_url Then
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If 'explorer.LocationURL = my_url
        End If 'explorer.name = "Internet Explorer"
    Next

    If Not found Then
        If Not IE_sub Is Nothing Then
            IE_sub.navigate my_url, 2048 'new tab
        Else
            Set IE_sub = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            IE_sub.Silent = True
            IE_sub.Visible = True
            IE_sub.TheaterMode = True
            IE_sub.navigate my_url
        End If 'Not isnothing(IE_sub)
    End If

    Set GetIE = IE_sub

    Set shellWins = Nothing
    Set explorer = Nothing
End Function
```

I understand what is happening, but I am unable to figure out how to access the parent/original IE instance and open a tab in that window vs. creating a new instance with two tabs. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I create a simple demo to test your code like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ql7g.png), but it can work normally (windows 10 20H2, IE11), it will open new tab in existed IE instance instead of opening a new IE instance. Can you provide more information, such as operating system version? This will help solve the issue, thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @XudongPeng, thanks for the reply! When I click "About" in IE it says: Windows 10 Enterprise Version 20H2 (OS Build 19042.1165). So, I am not sure the exact IE version number, but I think it is 10.  I am not using Edge, but the older IE ("e" with the yellow swish around it).  Thanks again and I agree the code should work as it is currently written.

Comment: Thank you for providing these details. I think you should be using `IE 11` instead of IE 10 in `windows 10 20H2`. As I mentioned, I tested in IE 11, I think it has nothing to do with Edge. But my operating system version is a little different, it is windows 10 20H2 (OS Build 19042.928).